# C++ TCP socket garbage value

Tags: c++, sockets

I have my socket comms pretty much working. The only thing that I'm not sure about is why I'm getting some garbage values at the end of my message. The first message I send contains some extra characters at the end, and every message after that is as expected...does anyone have any insight as to why this is happening?

**Send:**

```
CString string = "TEST STRING TO SEND";
char* szDest;
szDest = new char[string.GetLength()];
strcpy(szDest,string);
m_pClientSocket->Send(szDest,strlen(pMsg));
```

**Receive: (this is using Qt)**

```
char* temp;
int size = tcpSocket->bytesAvailable();
temp = new char[size];
tcpSocket->read(temp,size);
```

Comment: It's a pretty fair guess that without seeing some code, none of us can or will have a clue.

Comment: The code you've shown is fine. What isn't fine is the rest of your code. For example, how do you print it? Try to print `std::string(temp, size)`.

Comment: Are you sure the size from bytesAvailable is getting the same size as the size of the data you sent? If you send less data than what bytesAvailable reports back, the code could read garbage values into the array to fill up the space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will be missing the \0 in your temp after read, since it's not really transmitted (and probably shouldn't be)

You likely need to change the receive a little bit:

```
temp = new char[size + 1];
int realSize = tcpSocket->read(temp, size);
temp[realSize] = 0;
```

Btw, you would be better off with QTcpSocket::readAll() in this little snipped.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this `CString` class, but I see two bugs here:

- Does `GetLength()` include the terminating NUL? If not, your `char` buffer is one byte smaller than it needs to be, and the `strcpy` is clobbering memory after the end of the buffer.
- `strlen(pMsg)` is the length of something other than `szDest`.  This is probably the immediate cause of your problem.

The `char` buffer appears to be unnecessary: why don't you just do

```
CString string = "TEST STRING TO SEND";
m_pClientSocket->Send(string, string.GetLength());
```

?