# garbage send from python3 client to cpp server

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I have a CPP server and python3 client but when I'm sending data I'm getting garbage values (wrong numbers and \0 in the middle of the string)
i tried to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332973/c-server-cannot-read-my-message-from-python-client-via-socket) and also [C++ TCP socket garbage value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420393/c-tcp-socket-garbage-value).

the client code (python3):

```
MESSAGE = "HELLO WORLD"
def send_via_socket(message):
    print(len(message))
    s.send(bytes([len(message)]))
    data = pack('<Q%ds' % len(message), len(message), message.encode())
    s.send(data)
    return True

SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Create a socket object
ans = s.connect((SERVER_IP, PORT))
if ans is None:
     write_to_log('connection to server establish')
     send_via_socket(MESSAGE)
else:
     write_to_log('connection failed')
     message = s.recv(1024)
     write_to_log(str(message, 'utf-8'))
     res = res
except socket.error as err:
    message = f"socket creation failed with error %s" % err
    write_to_log(message)
    return res
```

and the read function in the server (cpp)

```
int Server::readString(int fd, std::string &str)
{
    size_t len;
    char *buf;

    auto bytesReceived =read(fd, &len, sizeof(len));
    if(bytesReceived == -1)
    {
        return bytesReceived;
    }
    buf = new char[len];
    bytesReceived = read(fd, buf, len);
    if(bytesReceived == -1)
    {
        return bytesReceived;
    }

    str.assign(buf, len);
    delete []buf;
    return bytesReceived;
}
```

I also have a CPP client and its work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer that I found at the end was using [Oleguer Canal functions](https://github.com/OleguerCanal/cpp-python-socket/blob/optional_opencv/cpp/cpp_sockets/src/client.cpp)

its solves all the garbage problome

Comment: Holly shit, just saw you linked my repo! Happy to be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

This might fail, once the length of the encoded message is not equal to the length of the original message -- happens a lot, once you start sending UTF-8 or anything besides plain ASCII:

```
data = pack('<Q%ds' % len(message), len(message), message.encode())
```

You might be better off using `protobuf` or something like `ZeroMQ` for sending your data. Easy to implement in any language, and you don't have to count bytes anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
s.send(bytes([len(message)]))
```

Sends the length as a single byte.

```
auto bytesReceived =read(fd, &len, sizeof(len));
```

Reads the length as a size_t, which is more than a single byte.